# Show Incoming links on wiki page

Tags: 2010, wiki

How can I show incoming links on the wiki page itself in SharePoint 2010?

Currently, there is a link on the right like in the picture below that allows you to navigate to a page that only has incoming links. I would like to be able to display the incoming links on the wiki page itself to make the wiki as a whole easier to navigate.

[image: Picture showing wiki page with incoming links]

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested int he JQuery and CEWP then you can try it.

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { 

function addLinks(){

//get the url for the incoming links page
var starturl = SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('BackLinks.aspx');

var builder = new SP.Utilities.UrlBuilder(starturl);
builder.addKeyValueQueryString('List', (new SP.Guid(_spPageContextInfo.pageListId)).toString());
builder.addKeyValueQueryString('ID', _spPageContextInfo.pageItemId.toString());
var u = builder.get_url();

//create a target container and load it with the incoming links 
//filtered to show the links list only 

var l = $("<div id='incomingLinks' style='border-top: solid 1px silver'>").load(u + " #MSO_ContentTable .ms-bodyareacell", function(){

l.css("font-size", "11pt").find("a").css("padding-left", "11px").css("font-size", "11pt");
});

//append the new container to the wiki content 


$(".ms-wikicontent").append(l);


}
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(addLinks, "sp.js"); 


});
```

[Show Incoming Links on a Wiki Page - for SharePoint 2010](http://jtlovessharepoint.blogspot.com/2010/09/show-incoming-links-on-wiki-page-for.html)

http://mo.notono.us/2009/01/moss-add-incoming-links-to-wiki-page.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to create either custom webpart or use JavaScript.

Here is a [free web part](http://weblogs.asp.net/wkriebel/sharepoint-wiki-page-incoming-links-web-part) which states what you does. Note - I haven't tested this.

JavaScript approach is explained on [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/28ef9b01-57e9-448a-ba36-f1e68ad1e915/wiki-related-articles-web-part?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious) thread.

Comment: Can you add the relevant information from the links to your answer and use the link as a source of additional information? http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/189763 Would it be necessary to add this webpart or javascript on each wiki page?

Comment: @RyanGates yes if you want to go the hard way. Best practice is to add this to the wiki page layout and create pages out of that.